# Is there a way to improve rule performance?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm attempting to pair tasks (runs) and leverage a limited set of facts without instantiating all the possible combinations.  While the following rule is not complete yet, performance is very slow.  I'm looking for suggestions.

```
when
$rp : RoutePair()

accumulate( RouteRun( routePair == $rp,  $runId : runId);
            $routeRunListAm : collectList($runId),
            $count : count();
            $count == 4)
accumulate( $pr : PairableRuns( (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[1])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[2])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[3])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[1] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[2])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[1] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[3])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[2] && runId2 == $routeRunListAm.toArray()[3]));
            $pairableRunsListPm : collectList($pr),
            $count : count();
            $count >= 2)
accumulate( RouteRun( routePair == $rp,  $returnRunId : returnRunId);
            $routeRunListPm : collectList($returnRunId))
accumulate( $pr : PairableRuns( (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[1])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[2])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[0] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[3])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[1] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[2])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[1] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[3])
                             || (runId1 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[2] && runId2 == $routeRunListPm.toArray()[3]));
            $pairableRunsListPm : collectList($pr),
            $count : count();
            $count >= 2)
```

then

Comment: Why `toArray()[x]`? Isn't `get(x)` just as good?

Comment: You are assuming that the collected list $routeRunListAm contains values in a certain order, because otherwise the asymmetric match with runId1 preceding runId2 would not make sense. I don't see how this order should happen since the accumulate isn't tied to a  deterministic sequence.

Comment: The PairableRuns fact and feasibility function would handle any order.  How can I get the list ordered?  That wouuld reduce the number of pairable runs verifications what would need to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to (ab)use an answer so that I can ask my questions to understand the problem.

```
class RoutePair{...}
class RouteRun( 
    RoutePair routePair;
    RunId runId
}
class PairableRuns(
    RunId runId1; // maybe String or int - doesn't matter
    RunId runId2;
}
```

After the first collect, `$routeRunListAm` is a List of 4 RouteRun objects, **in any order**. But the complex boolean expression will only return true if the order of runId1 and runId2 in some PairableRuns is reflected by the order in that list which has been accumulated in some indeterministic order.

I find it also somethat irritating that this List must have *exactly* 4 RouteRun objects - why not >= 4? The second part of the condition contains an almost identical combinations of CEs and constraints, except that here the condition `$count == 4` is missing from the third accumulate CE.

I'm not sure what the complex boolean expression should ascertain, but I think that the much simpler

```
$pr: PairableRuns( runId1 memberOf $routeRunListAm,
                   runId2 memberOf $routeRunListAm )
```

should achieve the same thing.

However, I'm not sure whether that is really sufficient. Consider that $routeRunListAm contains `7, 12, 14, 22` and the PairableRuns `{7,12}`, `{7,14}`, `{7,22}`. This would match the original constraint as well as my proposed form three times - is this what is desired?

It's impossible to advise without a concise specification (which the rule as shown is definitely not).